# Best practice to respond restfully to a time consuming calculation (Node.js with Express)

Tags: node.js, rest, http, express, delay

Best way to respond restfully to a time consuming calculation (Node.js with Express)

I'm building a REST API using Node.js with Express.
Now I have to design the response to a time consuming calculation on the server side to a http request witch is ending up in a zip file with a few megabytes.
The calculation is done in a few seconds at the moment. But perhaps, if data grows up, it can take minutes sometime. So I think it's not the best way to wait in Express till data is ready and then res.sendfile() it back to the client. But what is the best solution?

Should I implement a delayed response with long polling? Like [http-delayed-response](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-delayed-response)

- What I don't like here is that I immediately have to report HTTP 202. If the generation of the ZIP file fails, I have to deal with this in the response and cannot report it via HTTP status code. Also I cannot respond the file directly - as far as I know.

Or something with job ids and states to each job? Like [express-delayed-response](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-delayed-response)

- In this way my API is not stateless anymore and I have to build a status handler.

Are there better and more established solutions to this problem?

Comment: I worked on a project which had a long running process.  We decided to respond immediately with a success message and later, after the processing was done, trigger an email with the link to the results to the user. Not sure if this is an option for your usecase. Thought I'd just put it out there

Comment: I think a status handler (not talking about that delayed response now) can be very restful. Add an endpoint where the status of the calculation can be checked, and let the client handle the problem of checking the endpoint. When the calculation completes you could make an update-status request to your rest-api to bring it to a full circle.

Comment: Establish websocket connection to your server and send statuses to the client. When the process is done, send message through socket and load file from client side.